# How to precisely check the position of an animated element in Android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, game-engine

I want to develop a small game where an orange rectangle is animated from the right to the left on the display and when it is in the middle (green rectangle) the user should press a button and gets points if he/she succeeds (see Screenshot):
[image]

Here is the code of the game class

```
public class Test extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    /*
    Game variables
     */

    public static final int DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 100;
    ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle> arrayList_GameEventRectangles;
    private int currentTimeSlot;
    private boolean gameIsRunning;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int timeslotsEventElementUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 = (int)(5.0 * (1000.0/DELAY_IN_MILLIS));
    private int numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 = 5000;

    //Fix parameters of the UI elements
    private float horizontalPercentageOfScoreRectangle_End = 0.491f;
    private float horizontalPercentageOfScoreRectangle_Start = 0.567f;
    private float verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine = 0.049f;
    private float percentageHeightOfEventElement = 0.071f;


    int widthDisplay;
    int heightDisplay;
    int helpCounterRun =0;
    int helpCounterUpdateScreen =0;
    int helpCounterCountDownTime =0;

    private FragmentTestBinding binding;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    ConstraintSet constraintSet ;

    //Variables for the single view event
    View_Game_Event_Rectangle[] viewEvent;

    private boolean fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;
    private CountDownTimer cdt;
    private  final long DURATION = 900000L;
    private  final long DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER = 100;

    private int numberOfTimeSlotsUntilTheEndOfScreen = (int)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * 2/(DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER));
    private int currentLevel;
    public Test() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        arrayList_GameEventRectangles = new ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle>();
        currentLevel = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getWindowManager();
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        widthDisplay = size.x;
        heightDisplay = size.y;
        container.getContext();
        constraintLayout= binding.constraintLayout;
        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = true;
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;
        constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        startGame();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }


    public void startGame () {
        gameIsRunning = true;
        Log.e("LogTag_El", "-------Start Game------" );

        //Create rectangle-element that should be animated from the right to the left on the screen
        arrayList_GameEventRectangles.add(new View_Game_Event_Rectangle(getActivity(), "Bulb Rectangle", 100, 20));
        countDownTime();
    }


    private void updateScreen() {

        for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {

            //Create view and set
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 50) {

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setActive(true);


                //Set the parameters and the backgrund of the view element
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));

                if(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getEventType().equals("Bulb Rectangle")) {
                    arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_bulb_1).mutate());
                }

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setId(View.generateViewId());

                //Make the view invisible (before it's appearence time)
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                // Set the ConstraintLayout programatically for the view
                constraintLayout.addView(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement));
                constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
                constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), percentageHeightOfEventElement);

                float widthConstrainPercentage_element1 = (float)(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration() / 100.0);
                float duration = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration();

                constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), widthConstrainPercentage_element1);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

                float horizontalBias = 1.0f ;
                constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), horizontalBias);
                constraintSet.setVerticalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine);
                constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

            }


            //Shift the view to the right border of the display
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 40) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setTranslationX(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getWidth());
            }


            //Animate view element
            if (currentTimeSlot ==arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot()) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                long durationForTheAnimation = (long)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * 1);

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).animate().setDuration(durationForTheAnimation).translationX(widthDisplay*(-1)).start();

            }
            helpCounterUpdateScreen++;
            checkPositionsOfActiveElements();

        }

    }

    private void countDownTime(){

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(DURATION, DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER) {
            boolean delay = true;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(delay) {
                    delay = false;
                } else {

                    helpCounterCountDownTime++;
                    currentTimeSlot++;

                    updateScreen();
                    delay = true;
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                updateScreen();
            }
        }.start();

    }

    public void checkPositionsOfActiveElements () {
        for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {
            //Check if the view is still running
            if (arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).isActive() == true && currentElement==0) {
                Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", "currentTimeSlot: " + currentTimeSlot);
                Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", "currentElement.getX(): " + arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getX());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Reset your variable to false
        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;

        // And clean up any postDelayed callbacks that are waiting to fire
        cdt.cancel();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML-layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/imageView_TargetRectangle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"


        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.16"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.10" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_action"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Action"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.102"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.373"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.745"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.13" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To animate the view and to count down the time I use the handler `CountDownTimer`. Actually the animation itself works (I first shift the invisible orange rectangle to the very right and then make it visible after a certain time and animate it). To problem is, that I can not precisely determine where the orange rectangle is. I can only determine it after a certain timespan and this is not enough for what I want to do.

Here is the output of the LogTag:

```
2023-03-14 18:37:40.318 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 100
2023-03-14 18:37:40.320 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 2028.0
2023-03-14 18:37:40.617 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 101
2023-03-14 18:37:40.618 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 2013.0167
2023-03-14 18:37:40.857 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 102
2023-03-14 18:37:40.857 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 1972.158
2023-03-14 18:37:41.149 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 103
2023-03-14 18:37:41.150 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 1883.3052
2023-03-14 18:37:41.403 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 104
2023-03-14 18:37:41.403 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 1780.0686
2023-03-14 18:37:41.668 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 105
2023-03-14 18:37:41.669 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 1634.5706
2023-03-14 18:37:41.931 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-03-14 18:37:41.936 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 1495.0557
2023-03-14 18:37:42.185 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 107
2023-03-14 18:37:42.186 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 1317.382
2023-03-14 18:37:42.481 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 108
2023-03-14 18:37:42.481 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentElement.getX(): 1088.4066
2023-03-14 18:37:42.760 15544-15544/com.example.game E/LogTag_FGa_CP: currentTimeSlot: 109
```

As you can see, the x-positions of the orange rectangle decrease by a huge amount of pixels when I check it (e.g. 1972.158, 1883.3052, 1780.0686). What I actually want to have is a method, that can return each of the positions of the orange rectangle, meaning: 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969 etc.. This way, I could make sure - after pressing the button - to get the exact position of the orange rectangle.

**Reminder**: Please can anyone tell me how to do this? I really need this in my app and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

> What I actually want to have is a method, that can return each of the positions of the orange rectangle, meaning: 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969 etc..

The rectangle won't necessarily appear at these locations (1972, 1971, etc.) even though the animation spans these locations. Android devices compose what is displayed at a rate of 60 frames per second ([Frame Rate](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/frame-rate)) (or maybe 90 FPS or 120 FPS for some devices). For 60 FPS, a frame will be displayed every 16ms or so.

Let's consider an animation that animates the x position of a view from 0 to 1,000 pixels over one second. The animation has these three constraints:

1. The animation must last for one second;
2. The animation must move 1,000 pixels;
3. The animation must adhere to the 60 FPS display rate.

To satisfy these conditions, the animation must move the view an average of 1,000/16 pixels or 62.5 pixels for each frame assuming a constant speed.

So, one would expect the x value to follow the sequence "0, 62.5, 125, 187.5, ..." which skips a lot of positions. This is no different from how a motion picture projector operates. Each frame of a movie represents a quantized leap in time.

Given all this, one solution would be to determine a range of positions that constitutes a successful tap on the button based upon the forgoing. You could also create an animation that moves one pixel at a time but, due to the frame rate constraint, the animation may be too slow since you could move at most 60 pixels each second.

---

---

Here is some additional information that may help:

- Once the animation begins, you can determine the placement of the animated view at any time by checking [View#getX()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getX()).

> The visual x position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to the translationX property plus the current left property.

It is the `translationX` property that is being animated.

- In the on-click listener, retrieve the "x" position of the animated view as stated above and compare that with the range that corresponds to the area that the user should be trying to hit.

This is the general outline, although you may need to make other adjustments to your code to accommodate this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you think of an approach how I can archieve what I want (check if the orange bar is inside the green rectangle). Somehow this has to be possible in Android since there are surely games in Android that also need to check the exact position of an animated object. I think your suggested approach "a range of positions that constitutes a successful tap on the button" doesnt work due to 2 reasons. First, the animation itself is not linear (so no constant shift for every timeslot in the game), moreover the `CountDownTimer` handler can only check at some specific timeslots.

Comment: Thanks Cheti camp for your answer. I have some follow up questions to your update:1) WHat do you mean by "It is the translationX property that is being animated." 2.) What type of "other adjustments to your code" are you referring to. 3) Do you think your suggested approach still works even if the handler `CountDownTimer ` only can update the screen after a certain time and can't do that continiously? As stated in my question, the basic problem is that the `View.getX()` can't be accessed at every position of the View and I want to know how I can still precicesly measure the position of a View

Comment: 1) The view is moved by Android animation code by adjusting the `translationX` value of the view; 2) "other adjustments" just means that I have not analyzed you code in detail, so you may need to make changes outside the scope of your question; 3) _View.getX()_ will give you the position of the view. You can grab that position when the button is pressed. Why do you need to know every position of the view when the button hasn't been pressed? I am unclear why that is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks Cheticamp or your answer. I upvoted it, accepted it and awarded the bounty to you.

Comment: Hi Cheticamp. I have to admit I was a little bit to fast accepting your answer. I tried it out and your approach leads to the same drawback. It just can't precisely measure the position of the active element. I use the bottom with a `new RepeatListener(3, 3, new View.OnClickListener()` and the outputs when holding the button pressed are e.g. "1559", "1548", "1501", "1488". This is more precise than before but still way to inprecise. I would like to have "1559", "1558", "1557" etc. to precisely measure, if the bottom was pressed at the right time.

Comment: If I understand your issue, you are expecting the view you are animating to be drawn at every pixel between the starting and ending points. The view will NOT be drawn at every pixel as you expect, but every few pixels or so due to a finite [Frame Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate). If the view has to be drawn at every pixel (still not sure why), you will have to explicitly change the `translatioX` value of the view with an  _ValueAnimator_ but, as I state in my answer, this may just be too slow since you will be looking at a max speed of 60 pixels/second (maybe 120 pps).

Comment: You can, however, compute where the view would be if you had a non-finite frame rate. For the animation, and assuming constant velocity, the position would be start_position + (total_pixels * (click_time - start_time) / total_time). Once computed, you could even nudge the view to the computed position. The "nudge" would most likely not be noticeable by the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I don't expect the View to be drawn at every pixel. What I want is to know exactly where the orange rectangle is, when the button is pressed. I have a Repeat Listener that constantly presses the button when it is pressed and hold. You can see from the output, that the inverval in which the position is returned using your approach is not really precise ("1559", "1548", "1501", "1488".). What I want is to have a precise measurement "1559", "1558", "1557" when the RepeatButton is pressed.

Comment: As the animation is not linear, you second suggested approach with the calculation also does not work.  It would lead to very inprecise values for the location of the view. Do you have any idea, how I can precisely know where the orange rectangle is when the button is pressed? Somehow this has to be possible. The biggest problem I see is the handler and CountDownTimer which unforunately don't make it possible to check from the methods itself where the precise location of the animated object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. Any comments to my last 2 comments? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: There is no secret variable that holds a "precise" position for the animated view. Getting the fractional value from the [Interpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator) is going to be your best bet. Again, the view will not be drawn at every possible position but, with an interpolator, you can calculate where it would be at any point in time. It is all deterministic.

Comment: @thanks for the comment. "Getting the fractional value from the Interpolator is going to be your best bet". how can i get the values from the interpolator and how can i make sure that the animation has constant velocity because at the momemt it does not

Comment: Thanks Cehticamp for your comment. Any comments to my last comment about the interpolator? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Any furhter comments? Will be good if you can say a little bit more about your interpolator approach that you were suggesting.

Comment: I don't really have anything more to say on this topic other than what I have posted here. It could be that I don't really understand your objectives. You can always post another question to try to get beyond this impasse.

Comment: If I posted a new question it would be exactly the same as this one. I just want to know how I can precisely check the position of an animated element in Android. Your suggest approaches do not archieve that. Your first suggested approach (just checking the tanslationX coordinate when pressing the button) is imprecise as you can see on my comments. Your second suggested approach with the interpolator is not really clear to me as the animation does not have the speed (also see my question and comments). So how can I use your interpolator approach and is it really suitable here

Comment: It's `View#getX()` not the `translationX` property the you should check to get the position of the bar (this would be the position in 16ms increments). My other suggestion is to get the interpolator from the animation and feed it the elapsed animation time (computed at the time of the click). From there you can determine how far the bar has moved and add that to the original position of the bar. This would be a _precise_ position at the time of the click which I believe is what you really want. It will likely be close to but different from the `getX()` position due to frame rate.

Comment: I suggest a new question incorporating anything that you have learned since to elucidate the problem. A new question may garner new answers while this question would likely not. (I would not try to answer the new question since my answer would likely not change.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Could you ellaborate a little bit more on your other approach"My other suggestion is to get the interpolator from the animation and feed it the elapsed animation time (computed at the time of the click). From there you can determine how far the bar has moved and add that to the original position of the bar. This would be a precise position at the time of the click which I believe is what you really want.". I don't really understand how to do this and I am sceptical that I can get really a precise position as the animation does not have constant speed.

Comment: Any comments on my last comments? I awarded a bouty to you of 50 points (which is quite much considering my total amount of points). So I'll appreciate if you can elaborate a little bit more about your second suggested approach because your first approach is not precise and does not answer this question. I'll appreciate every further comment.

Comment: Any further comments about your second approach?

Comment: Any further comments Cheti? You did not tell me much about your second suggested approach. So I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you, as I don't know how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: I don't really have anything more to add other than to say that you are right - the interpolator is not linear but is of the accelerate/decelerate variety. (At least on my emulator.) My suggestion still stands to work with the interpolator: You will have to try it out to see what you can get to work. If you are not satisfied, I suggest another question and posting what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You wrote "My  suggestion still stands to work with the interpolator" --> How exactly can I work with the interpolator? Is this a special Java class? Further you wrote " If you are not satisfied, I suggest another question and posting what you have tried." I am definitely not satifsfied with the suggestion. So when I post a new question it would be exactly the same question as this where I also showed what I have tried. Stackoverflow does not allow that.

Comment: You wrote "My suggestion still stands to work with the interpolator" --> How exactly can I work with the interpolator? Is this a special Java class?

Comment: @Hi Cheti. Any comment on my last comments about the interpolator approach that you suggested? Could you please tell me a little bit more about it as I really don't know how to proceed

Comment: See [this](https://jebware.com/interp/android-animation-interpolators.html?#) for what an interpolator is. You can get the interpolator from the animation. It will make sense with some research.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I use the LinearInterpolator? As you can see in my question, the movement of the animated views is not linear

Comment: any comment to my last comment? Unforunately I still have no clue what to do in order to precisely check the position of an animated element in Android which was the reason for my question here. So I'll highly appreciate every further comment especially on the Interpolator approach that you suggested as I don't know at all how to proceed.

Comment: Hi Cheti, it's me again still having the problem of precisely measuring the position of an animate element in Android. As you suggested, I asked a new question and showed what I have done (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367247/how-to-precisely-check-the-position-of-an-animated-element-in-android-with-a-rep). Maybe you can have a look at it. I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you as I don't know how to proceed

Comment: As you suggested I posted a new question with what I tried (there is also a bounty on it currently). Would you mind having a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367247/how-to-precisely-check-the-position-of-an-animated-element-in-android-with-a-rep. I'll be quite thankful as I have already tried a lot without any success.

Comment: I saw that post but it looks a lot like this post, so I have nothing to add beyond what I have said here. You are looking for something that simply does not exist. During animation, the view being animated will not move to every single pixel in the path but will jump pixels as I tried to explain above. The locations that are drawn is dependent upon the length of the path, the duration of the animation, the frame rate and the interpolator used.

Comment: Thanks Cheti for your comment. I have to admit that I have a hard time believing that what I want is in fact not possible. There are a lot of Android games where the position of elements has to be precisely known. With the approach I currently use, the position is not precisely measured at all.

Comment: Consider checking that the position you capture is within a certain number of pixels of the target position. You would have to see what value works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As my measuring approach is extremely imprecise, I have no clue how to "checking that the position you capture is within a certain number of pixels of the target position." as you suggested. There are pixel jumps of more than 100 pixels for successive measuring requests. So this would be more or less random guessing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using x and y, you could also get the exact location on the screen:

Java

```
    var location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

Kotlin

```
    val location = IntArray(2)
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pim. I tried to print the result of your suggested code by using                `int [] location = new int [2];
                Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", "arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getLocationOnScreen(location): " + arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getLocationOnScreen(location));`and I get the error messge "Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'void'". Further, I don't think that this approach solves the problem. The problem is the frequeny in which the methods are called that return the position of the element

Comment: Your print fails because it is concatenating incompatible data.  You can fix this by using:    int[] location = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getLocationOnScreen(location);                                                                             
Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", String.format("getLocOnScreen | x: %d | y: %d ", location[0], location[1]));

Comment: @RandomLonelyDev: Thanks Random for your comment. Your posted code can't be correct (even without trying). You define an array  with the name `location` and during the definition of it you use it as an argument for a method by using your suggested code `int[] location = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getLocationOnScreen(location);` . That would be a recursive definition of an array possible in Java (and in general from a logical point of view does not make any sense).

Comment: @Pim Tegelaar: 
Thanks for your answer Pim. Any comment about my last comments about the error that I get when applying your suggested code (and my assumtion that you approach in general does not solve my problem). I'll highly appreciate every further comment by you.

Comment: It is kind of strange API indeed, that alters the content of the array you pass as argument, instead of returning one. So it is indeed a void method. This also explains the error message you get.
The log message that @RandomLonelyDev posted is correct:
`Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", String.format("getLocOnScreen | x: %d | y: %d ", location[0], location[1]));`