# How to precisely check the position of an animated element in Android with a RepeatListener

Tags: java, android, android-animation, game-engine

I want to develop a small game where an orange rectangle is animated from the right to the left on the display and when it is in the middle (green rectangle) the user should press a button and gets points if he/she succeeds (see Screenshot):
[image]

Here is the code of the game class

```
public class Test extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    /*
    Game variables
     */

    public static final int DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 100;
    ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle> arrayList_GameEventRectangles;
    private int currentTimeSlot;
    private boolean gameIsRunning;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int timeslotsEventElementUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 = (int)(5.0 * (1000.0/DELAY_IN_MILLIS));
    private int numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 = 5000;

    //Fix parameters of the UI elements
    private float horizontalPercentageOfScoreRectangle_End = 0.491f;
    private float horizontalPercentageOfScoreRectangle_Start = 0.567f;
    private float verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine = 0.049f;
    private float percentageHeightOfEventElement = 0.071f;


    int widthDisplay;
    int heightDisplay;
    int helpCounterRun =0;
    int helpCounterUpdateScreen =0;
    int helpCounterCountDownTime =0;

    private FragmentTestBinding binding;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    ConstraintSet constraintSet ;

    //Variables for the single view event
    View_Game_Event_Rectangle[] viewEvent;

    private boolean fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;
    private CountDownTimer cdt;
    private  final long DURATION = 900000L;
    private  final long DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER = 100;

    private int numberOfTimeSlotsUntilTheEndOfScreen = (int)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * 2/(DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER));
    private int currentLevel;
    public Test() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        arrayList_GameEventRectangles = new ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle>();
        currentLevel = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getWindowManager();
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        widthDisplay = size.x;
        heightDisplay = size.y;
        container.getContext();
        constraintLayout= binding.constraintLayout;

        // Define and registrate RepeatListener on the heat button

        binding.buttonAction.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener) new RepeatListener(1, 1, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // the code to execute repeatedly
                checkPositionsOfActiveElements();
                }
            }
        ));


        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = true;
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;
        constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        startGame();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }


    public void startGame () {
        gameIsRunning = true;
        Log.e("LogTag_El", "-------Start Game------" );

        //Create rectangle-element that should be animated from the right to the left on the screen
        arrayList_GameEventRectangles.add(new View_Game_Event_Rectangle(getActivity(), "Bulb Rectangle", 100, 20));
        countDownTime();
    }


    private void updateScreen() {

        for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {

            //Create view and set
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 50) {

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setActive(true);


                //Set the parameters and the backgrund of the view element
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));

                if(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getEventType().equals("Bulb Rectangle")) {
                    arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_bulb_1).mutate());
                }

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setId(View.generateViewId());

                //Make the view invisible (before it's appearence time)
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                // Set the ConstraintLayout programatically for the view
                constraintLayout.addView(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement));
                constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
                constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), percentageHeightOfEventElement);

                float widthConstrainPercentage_element1 = (float)(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration() / 100.0);
                float duration = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration();

                constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), widthConstrainPercentage_element1);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

                float horizontalBias = 1.0f ;
                constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), horizontalBias);
                constraintSet.setVerticalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine);
                constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

            }


            //Shift the view to the right border of the display
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 40) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setTranslationX(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getWidth());
            }


            //Animate view element
            if (currentTimeSlot ==arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot()) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                long durationForTheAnimation = (long)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * 1);

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).animate().setDuration(durationForTheAnimation).translationX(widthDisplay*(-1)).start();

            }
            helpCounterUpdateScreen++;

        }

    }

    private void countDownTime(){

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(DURATION, DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER) {
            boolean delay = true;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(delay) {
                    delay = false;
                } else {

                    helpCounterCountDownTime++;
                    currentTimeSlot++;

                    updateScreen();
                    delay = true;
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                updateScreen();
            }
        }.start();

    }

    public void checkPositionsOfActiveElements () {
        for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {
            //Check if the view is still running
            if (arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).isActive() == true && currentElement==0) {
                Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", "currentTimeSlot: " + currentTimeSlot);
                Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", "currentElement.getX(): " + arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getX());

                //int[] location = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getLocationOnScreen(location);
                
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Reset your variable to false
        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;

        // And clean up any postDelayed callbacks that are waiting to fire
        cdt.cancel();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML-layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/imageView_TargetRectangle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"


        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.16"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.10" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_action"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Action"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.102"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.373"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.745"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.13" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the output when I hold the action button pressed while the orange rectanlge is visible:

```
2023-05-30 19:09:23.292 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1634.5706
2023-05-30 19:09:23.312 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.313 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1625.5212
2023-05-30 19:09:23.344 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.344 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1615.8167
2023-05-30 19:09:23.359 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.359 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1596.7167
2023-05-30 19:09:23.376 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.376 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1586.7451
2023-05-30 19:09:23.393 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.393 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1576.6847
2023-05-30 19:09:23.410 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.410 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1567.1366
2023-05-30 19:09:23.427 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.427 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1556.908
2023-05-30 19:09:23.442 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.442 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1547.2031
2023-05-30 19:09:23.459 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.459 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1536.8103
2023-05-30 19:09:23.475 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.475 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1526.3347
2023-05-30 19:09:23.493 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.493 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1515.7773
2023-05-30 19:09:23.510 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentTimeSlot: 106
2023-05-30 19:09:23.510 26983-26983 LogTag_FGa_CP           com.example.game                     E  currentElement.getX(): 1505.7678
```

As you can see the output does not precisely give me the exact location of the orange rectangle because even with 1 millisecond (the lowest) in the RepeatListener, I get the location values: 1634, 1625, 1615, 1596 etc. What I actually want is to also return values from the `checkPositionsOfActiveElements` method when the orange rectangle is at 1634, 1633, 1632, 1631, 1630. With my current approach, I just get imprecise discrete values. But I don't get the values of the location between the outputed discrete positions. My question is what I can do in order to get the precise location of the orange rectanlge while it is visible such that I can archieve my aim of determining if the orange rectangle was within the green one when the action button was pressed. With the current approach I can't because of the imprecise nature of the location reporting.

**Reminder**: My bounty is about to expire within one day. So please, if you have any idea, I'll be very very thankful if you could share it with me.

Comment: What if instead of using a view and animating it through `View.animate()` you use a custom view that draws a rectangle and updates the position using a `ValueAnimator`?


Sidenote: you can use a ForEach loop instead of the for loop inside the `updateScreen` method. 

Use `for (View_Game_Event_Rectangle currentElement : arrayList_GameEventRectangles)`  instead of `for (int currentElement =0; currentElement<arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++)` and `currentElement` instead of `arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement)`

Answer (score 0):

The animation will not display the orange rectangle at every pixel in the path due to Android's finite frame rate. You may see the rectangle displayed at each pixel for some very specific circumstances, but that will generally not be the case.

Here is what I suggest:

1. Divide the animation into three segments: the first from the start position to the right edge of the green rectangle; the second from the right edge of the green rectangle to the left edge of the green rectangle, and the third from the left edge of the green rectangle to the left end of the animation. You can chain these animations together.
2. If the user clicks the button during the animation that is running in the middle, then it is a "hit", otherwise, it is a "miss."

By doing it this way, it won't matter how the orange rectangle gets to the center - skipping pixels or even skipping frames.

You can modify the start and stop position of the middle animation to fine tune it if you want such as making the middle animation much smaller if you want the user to try for the center of the green rectangle.

---

---

I put together a small app that demonstrates splitting the animation into three segments and three separate animations that look like one animation. (See below.) To do this, I had to use a [LinearInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LinearInterpolator) to make the transition seamless.

You can try this code out to see if it helps you - it may or may not. You will still be limited by the frame rate of the device (60fps, 90fps, 120fps). This means, that for any length of movement beyond the shortest length, the app will skip pixels. For instance, moving a view 1,000 pixels in 2 seconds for a 60 fps device will show the view 120 times at 8.3 pixel increments (8.3 = 1,000/(2x60)). This assumes a fast device and an excution environment that is not too busy. If the device/emulator is slow or the environment is busy, you will see a varying number of varying gap sizes in the movement.

You may want to look at [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) for drawing the game. I don't have any real experience with it, but it seems to be used in games and may give you better results. It will get the app off of the main thread and will avoid much the the Android view system that can be slow.

Here is the code:

```
public class Test2 extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private FragmentTestBinding binding;

    // Assume moving rectangle moves from initial position to x = 0.
    private float moving_rectangle_full_shift = 0f;

    // The full shift is composed of three shifts
    private float moving_rectangle_shift_1 = 0f;
    private float moving_rectangle_shift_2 = 0f;
    private float moving_rectangle_shift_3 = 0f;

    private final long moving_rectangle_full_shift_duration = 2000L;

    // Each shift will last for a duration proportional to is size relative to the full shift.
    // This assumes a linear interpolator for the animation.
    private long moving_rectangle_shift_1_duration = 0L;
    private long moving_rectangle_shift_2_duration = 0L;
    private long moving_rectangle_shift_3_duration = 0L;

    // Set to chain the three animations together.
    private final AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

    private float lastTransX = 0f;
    private int frameCount = 0;

    public Test2() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(requireActivity(), R.layout.fragment_test);
        binding.buttonAction.setOnTouchListener(this);
        binding.getRoot().addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                       int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                binding.getRoot().removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
                Log.d("Applog", String.format("Target between %d and %d",
                        binding.imageViewTargetRectangle.getLeft()
                                - binding.movingRectangle.getLeft(),
                        binding.imageViewTargetRectangle.getLeft() -
                                binding.imageViewTargetRectangle.getRight()));

                moving_rectangle_full_shift = -binding.movingRectangle.getX();
                moving_rectangle_shift_1 = -(-moving_rectangle_full_shift
                        - binding.imageViewTargetRectangle.getX()
                        - binding.imageViewTargetRectangle.getWidth());
                moving_rectangle_shift_1_duration =
                        (long) (abs(moving_rectangle_shift_1 / moving_rectangle_full_shift)
                                * moving_rectangle_full_shift_duration);

                moving_rectangle_shift_2 = -binding.imageViewTargetRectangle.getWidth();
                moving_rectangle_shift_2_duration = (long) (abs(moving_rectangle_shift_2
                        / moving_rectangle_full_shift) * moving_rectangle_full_shift_duration);

                moving_rectangle_shift_3 = -binding.imageViewTargetRectangle.getX();
                moving_rectangle_shift_3_duration = (long) (abs(moving_rectangle_shift_3
                        / moving_rectangle_full_shift) * moving_rectangle_full_shift_duration);

                ObjectAnimator translationAnimatorRight =
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.movingRectangle, "translationX",
                                moving_rectangle_shift_1);
                translationAnimatorRight.setDuration(moving_rectangle_shift_1_duration);

                ObjectAnimator translationAnimatorMiddle =
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.movingRectangle, "translationX",
                                moving_rectangle_shift_1 + moving_rectangle_shift_2);
                translationAnimatorMiddle.setDuration(moving_rectangle_shift_2_duration);

                ObjectAnimator translationAnimatorLeft =
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.movingRectangle, "translationX",
                                moving_rectangle_full_shift);
                translationAnimatorLeft.setDuration(moving_rectangle_shift_3_duration);
                animatorSet.playSequentially(
                        translationAnimatorRight,
                        translationAnimatorMiddle,
                        translationAnimatorLeft
                );

                // Must use a LinearInterpolator or there will be uneven movement.
                animatorSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        showStatus("Total miss!");
                    }
                });
                translationAnimatorMiddle.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                    float animatedValue = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    Log.d("Applog", String.format("transX = %f delta = %f frame #%d",
                            animatedValue, animatedValue - lastTransX, ++frameCount));
                    lastTransX = animatedValue;
                });
            }
        });

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (isAnimation2Running()) {
                animatorSet.cancel();
                showStatus("Hit!");
            } else if (isAnimatorSetStarted()) {
                animatorSet.cancel();
                showStatus("Miss!");
            } else {
                showStatus("");
                frameCount = 0;
                lastTransX = 0;
                animatorSet.start();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    private void showStatus(String text) {
        binding.status.setText(text);
    }

    private boolean isAnimation2Running() {
        return animatorSet.getChildAnimations().get(1).isRunning();
    }

    private boolean isAnimatorSetStarted() {
        return animatorSet.isStarted();
    }
}

**The layout used:**

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageView_TargetRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="Status goes here" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/imageView_TargetRectangle"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/moving_rectangle"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/moving_rectangle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Action"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView_TargetRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView_TargetRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_TargetRectangle" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As by bounty was running out of time I awarded it to you because you gave the only possible answer. But I still have some questions to your answer: 1) How can I divide the animation into three segments and how can I ensure, that the animation is still smooth and does not change its velocity after each segment? and how can I change the animations toghether 2) What do you mean by modifying the start and stop position of the middle animation? How can I do this? Would you mind telling me how to change the java code or at least which classes I need to use?

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. I have to admit that your suggested solution looks extremely complex especially considering that I normal game engine class is way more complex and contains more animations than the class file I uploaded. Is there not an easier way to do this? In my code it would be very difficult to set your variables like `moving_rectangle_shift_1`. Further, I work with ConstraintSet of the ConstraintLayout for the animation. Thus, I think it is not possible (or extremely time consuming) to adopt your suggested approach to my app. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry. I do not have any other suggestions given the scope of your question.